# Maintain Cell Value If Condition is True

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets

What formula can I use to maintain a cell value (Integer) in excel if a certain condition is True?

*Example;

A6=5

A7=4

A8= A6 * A7  - which will give a value of 20 (in Cell A8) in this case*.

*How can I maintain the 20 in cell A8 if the value of A6 was to be greater than 10 but allow is to change accordingly if it's less than 10?*

Comment: In it's most basic form: `=IF(A6>10,20,A6*A7)` but you haven't specified what the value should be when `A6` is 10.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: Are you using Excel or are you using Google Sheets?